# AWS API Proxy Lambda Invokes Lambda - Need Async Value Returned

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I have an AWS API using Lambda proxy integration. This API calls the Lambda function which calls an external long-running API. When using AWS API with proxy integration to call this Lambda I receive an error due to the 29 second limit AWS API Gateway has in place.

How can I return a response to the API from my Lambda when it's invoked, but allow the Lambda to continue to run and make the external API call.

The solution I am currently trying is using API Gateway with proxy integration to call a Lambda function (call it Lambda A) which calls my long-running Lambda (Lambda B).

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
region: 'us-west-2' //change to your region
});

lambda.invoke({
FunctionName: 'Lambda_B',
Payload: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2) // pass params

}, function(error, data) {
if (error) {
context.done('error', error);
}
if(data.Payload){
context.succeed(JSON.parse(data.Payload));
}
});
```

I then return a value from Lambda B with

```
context.succeed(response);
```

However Lambda B function does not continue to execute. Any help would be appreciated, new to Node Js.

```
<AccessDeniedException>
<Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to beauthorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

Comment: You could try something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272459/how-can-i-set-an-aws-lambda-to-be-invoked-asynchronously-through-http-api-gatewa/50273450#50273450

Comment: Your API needs to return the result of the long-running operation? Or you just need to respond with something?

Comment: @Pysul My API just needs to return something from Lambda B letting me know it has been invoked, then it should continue with no further response needed.

Comment: @NombreSanchez I haven't seen the `context` parameter used that way and Amazon doesn't list `.succeed` or `.error` as methods of it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

I think you want to use the `callback` parameter instead https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

In Lambda B you can call the callback right after the long running task starts to acknowledge that it started. Also make sure the long running task is under the 15 minute limit for lambdas.

Comment: I also don't know that you need to use 2 separate lambdas. If you just start the long running task in A and use the callback to respond something to Gateway, I think the Lambda should stay alive until its event loop clears when the long running task is done. But I can't find documentation about this.

Comment: I have implemented @JarredOlson and am using only the long-running Lambda with callback, now getting error that I poster below original post.

Comment: @Pysul... no.  The callback waits for the event loop to be empty *or* you can configure Lambda to freeze the container when the callback is called, even if the loop is not empty... either way, it is not possible to return a response and then continue doing work within the current container.

Comment: @NombreSanchez check this out--if you add a X-Amz-Invocation-Type:Event header to the integration request, you can call the lambda asynchronously from API Gateway https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html

Comment: @Pysul This is exactly what I need to accomplish!!. Thanks for the info!